# Is k-winner a biological plausible model of inhibition?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-modeling

In the Leabra cognitive architecture, sparse representations are created by simply ignoring all but the k strongest activations, if I understand correctly. In Hierarchical Temporal Memory, instead, each firing neuron inhibits an area of a given radius during this time step. To me, this seems more plausible due to the locality of neuronal connections.

Is the k-winner inhibition biologically plausible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by honi, it is possible to have bio plausible k-means. However, neither Leabra nor Hierarchical Temporal Memory (HTM) use it.

As Section 3.5.1 of How to Build a Brain by Chris Eliasmith notes:

> There are basic computational methods underlying Leabra that are of
>   dubious plausibility. The most evident is that Leabra directly applies
>   a k-Winner-Takes-All (kWTA) algorithm, which is acknowledged as
>   biologically implausible: “although the kWTA function is somewhat
>   biologically implausible in its implementation (e.g., requiring global
>   information about activation states and using sorting mechanisms), it
>   provides a computationally effective approximation to biologically
>   plausible inhibitory dynamics”
>   (http://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Leabra; see also O’Reilly
>   & Munakata [2000], pp. 94-105 for further discussion). In other words,
>   the actual dynamics of the system are replaced by an approximation
>   that is computationally cheaper on digital computers.

The same problem occurs with the HTM as discussed in [this forum post by Travis DeWolf](https://forum.nengo.ai/t/hierarchical-temporal-memory-vs-nef-spa/257/12?u=seanny123):

> In the second step of their spatial pooling, they
>   find the k most active columns, to apply learning to only these
>   columns. Dynamically, setting up WTA with lateral inhibitory
>   connections is notoriously very tricky, and isn't something that can
>   be done in a single time step. On top of that, controlling the
>   learning so that it's only applied after the network has settled on a
>   set of winners is a whole other issue. It might be the case it works
>   running the whole time as the WTA circuit settles, but the dynamics
>   are complex and can't just be assumed to work.

To summarize, k-winner inhibition is possible, but it's not used in a biologically plausible manner in either Leabra and HTM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see "[A Second Function of Gamma Frequency Oscillations: An E%-Max Winner-Take-All Mechanism Selects Which Cells Fire](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/29/23/7497.short)" by de Almeida, et al., 2009 for a biologically plausible implementation.